# Angular8 node js and npm installation problems

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm learning angular js. For this  I've install nodejs  and git. And I've run following command on CMD:

```
  npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

After some time following error occurred

```
npm WARN rollback Rolling back @schematics/angular@8.3.21 failed (this is 
probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\User 
Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@schematics'
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User 
Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\Chaitanya 
Kulkarni\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng' -> 
'C:\Users\Chaitanya Kulkarni\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01- 
04T12_12_30_922Z-debug.log
```

Can you please explain what is that error and how I could solve this. I am using Window 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this commands and manually delete the exist files if does not work.

Completely uninstall angular-cli from your machine

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

Clean npm cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Reinstall angular cli,

```
npm i @angular/cli@latest -g
```

Delete this file going to the location.

```
C:\Users\Chaitanya Kulkarni\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1
```

Answer (score 4):

Perform following steps:

1. Completely uninstall angular-cli from your machine 
   `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`
2. Clean npm cache 
   `npm cache clean --force`
3. Reinstall angular cli, 
   `npm i @angular/cli@latest -g`

Comment: This could help the author but from technical point is useless. It doesn't show why the problem occurs and why solution works? `Restart computer` also could help. Following such approach developer looses occasion to improve skills. I don't deny you advise, but this should be very last option.

Comment: when I run command npm cache clean --force then npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing. occur can you tell me what is that error

Comment: That warning comes when you run forcefully npm cache clean command. -f option specifes forcefully.

Comment: For me to make this solution fully working, I had to add to the reinstall command "--force".

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening the Command Prompt with Administrator privileges and then run the command.

Comment: Thanks for advise but I've try this also but not working same error occur

Comment: Tried that as well. Didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run following command in terminal

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest --force`

Comment: Tried that but npm didn't overwrite the files as promised. At least not on windows.

Comment: Try with sudo in front of it

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal navigate to the following path:
`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`
and delete angular file and reinstall cli.
That worked for me.

Also do check if you've set your path variables correctly.